# HTTPClient doesn't send HttpPost request

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I have acutally a problem with my Android HTTPClient.

I want to send POST data to a website and parse the content after this.
My problem is, that the POST data wasn't sent to the webserver.
I don't know why.

Here is my HTTP Util Class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class HTTPHelperUtil {

    private static HTTPHelperUtil instance;

    private String url;

    private List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    private String result;

    private HTTPHelperUtil() {
        // nothing to do
    }

    public synchronized static HTTPHelperUtil getInstance() {
        if (HTTPHelperUtil.instance == null) {
            HTTPHelperUtil.instance = new HTTPHelperUtil();
        }
        return HTTPHelperUtil.instance;
    }

    public HTTPHelperUtil init(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        this.url = url;
        this.nameValuePairs = nameValuePairs;
        return HTTPHelperUtil.instance;
    }

    public HTTPHelperUtil start() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, String> execute = sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(nameValuePairs);
        return HTTPHelperUtil.instance;
    }

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
            String res = "";
            List<NameValuePair> postPairs = params[0];
            System.out.println(postPairs.get(0));
            System.out.println(postPairs.get(1));
            if (postPairs != null && !postPairs.isEmpty()) {
                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                try {
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postPairs));
                    HttpResponse response;
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    if (response != null && response.getEntity() != null) {
                        InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        if (content != null) {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8"));
                            while (true) {
                                String addingSource = reader.readLine();
                                if (addingSource != null) {
                                    res = addingSource;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    return "-";
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return "-";
                }
            }
            System.out.println(res);
            return res;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            HTTPHelperUtil.this.result = result;
        }
    }

    public String getResult() {
        System.out.println("Result = " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

There is the call from my Activity:

```
        final String url = "http://example.com/app/mysite.php";

        List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        HTTPHelperUtil.getInstance().init(url, postParams);
        String result = "";
        try {
            HTTPHelperUtil.getInstance().start();
            result = HTTPHelperUtil.getInstance().getResult();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My test-page doesn't get the username and password via POST.

Does anyone see the mistake in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use any tool like Fiddler 2 or CharlesProxy to make sure that the request actually leaves your device and goes to the webserver?

Comment: Are you sure there is a connection? There are no e.printStackTrace() in the catch blocks of  HTTPHelperUtil. There you should return e.getMessage() (instead of a "_"). `HTTPHelperUtil.getInstance().start(); result = HTTPHelperUtil.getInstance().getResult();`. That can never work. You want to get the result right after the asynctask is started. That is to early. You have to wait until the asynctask is finished. Only when onPostExecute has executed the result is there.
`

Comment: yes I have a connection.

Comment: yes I know that will not work for now the retrive the response in the activiy where I call the utility method, but I debug in the util method and there I get the error from the page, that I haven't filled the POST variables.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code :

List  postParams = new ArrayList  (2);

Here you are passing 2 in the constructor which is not required while declaring the list with name value pair.
This might be the reason as rest all code seems fine.

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: You are passing integer 2 as parameter os arraylist with namevalue collection..while creating list in activity

Comment: That's the initialation. I don't see any mistake here.